# Custom JPanel with WindowBuilder causes crash

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, windowbuilder

I have designed a form using [WindowBuilder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/quick_start.html), part of the generated code is:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

I'm trying to make my own JPanel, with paint method:

```
private class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {

    public DisplayPanel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //Paint the graph. Note that x is to the right, y is down.
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(0,0,this.getWidth()-1,this.getHeight()-1);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean mouseDrag(Event evt, int x, int y) {
        System.out.println(x+", "+y);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, changing the constructor to:

```
JPanel panel = new DisplayPanel();
```

causes an error when switching to design view:

```
 WindowBuilder encountered unexpected internal error.

This could be caused by a WindowBuilder bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partial update, etc.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
Stack trace:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
    at javax.swing.Spring.checkArg(Spring.java:671)
    at javax.swing.Spring.width(Spring.java:640)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout.applyDefaults(SpringLayout.java:1074)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout.putConstraints(SpringLayout.java:1105)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout.getConstraints(SpringLayout.java:1140)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout$SpringProxy.getConstraint(SpringLayout.java:829)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout$SpringProxy.isCyclic(SpringLayout.java:853)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout.isCyclic(SpringLayout.java:907)
    at javax.swing.Spring$CompoundSpring.isCyclic(Spring.java:460)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout.isCyclic(SpringLayout.java:907)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout.abandonCycles(SpringLayout.java:919)
    at javax.swing.SpringLayout.layoutContainer(SpringLayout.java:1209)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.component.top.WindowTopBoundsSupport.apply(WindowTopBoundsSupport.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.AbstractComponentInfo.refresh_afterCreate(AbstractComponentInfo.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo.refreshCreate0(ObjectInfo.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo.access$0(ObjectInfo.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo$5$1.run(ObjectInfo.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo$5.run(ObjectInfo.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingUtils$2.run(SwingUtils.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingUtils.invokeLaterAndWait(SwingUtils.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.utils.SwingUtils.runLaterAndWait(SwingUtils.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.model.component.ComponentInfo.doRefresh(ComponentInfo.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.wb.core.model.ObjectInfo.refresh(ObjectInfo.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4113)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState_True(DesignPage.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState(DesignPage.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode$1.widgetSelected(DefaultMultiMode.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1200)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:2045)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3493)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Is this a bug? Or is there a different way to do this?

I tried setting the subclass in the gui designer, with right-click, Morph-subclass, but when I select DisplayPanel it gives an error:

```
new DisplayPanel((Mainwin) null) is not valid source for component creation, it references not existing constructor.
```

Comment: I don't use WindowsBuilder, but could you be altering code that shouldn't be altered? Most gui builders (that I know of), create generated code that is "protected" in that it should be controlled and altered by the builder software itself and not the user.

Comment: I think that's true for Netbeans' designer, but I was able to edit the code for WindowBuilder and it updated just fine. According to the documentation, it's ok to edit the generated code, it can even read code written by other gui designers: http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/faq.html#OtherGUIBuilders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the DisplayPanel from a private class in the window class, to a separate class. This eliminates the error.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Seems like a JTree caused that error for me.
I changed the JTree from static to "not static" and the error was gone.

When i tried for fun to change it back to static error was still gone...
(No other changes were made!)

I think that it is just a window builder bug.